# Running Kubernetes across cloud providers

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, amazon-eks

Our goal is to run kubernetes in AWS and Azure with minimal customization (setting up kubernetes managed env), support and maintenance. We need portability of containers across cloud providers.

Our preferred cloud provider is AWS. We are planning on running containers in EKS. We wanted to understand the customization effort required to run these containers in AKS.

Would you recommend choosing a container management platform like Pivotal Cloud Foundry or Redhat OpenShift or run them on AWS EKS or AKS where customization is less to run containers across different cloud providers.

Comment: define "customization effort required to run these containers in AKS". Apart from very minor things kubernetes works the same across cloud providers. you dont need to tweak anything for containers to run on it

Comment: Customization refers to setting up ingress controller, security , monitoring set up , network policies for prod communication,. Basically entire ecosystem around containers

Comment: thats just to broad, apart from networking annotation and pvc everything else is the same

Answer (score 2):

You need to define a common set of storage classes that map to similar volume types on each provider. If you are using some kind of provider based Ingress controller those can vary so I would recommend using an internal one like nginx or traefik. If you are using customization annotations for things like networking those can vary, but using those is pretty rare. Others k8s is k8s.